# Why do only turboprops have ground/flight idle selections?

Tags: jet-engine, turboprop, turbine

Why is it that only turboprops have a pilot controlled flight/ground idle and not jets?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Jets can have multiple "idle" settings, although the distinction generally isn't "flight idle" vs "ground idle".

For a jet aircraft, you *usually* want idle to be the minimum fuel consumption possible, so you want the slowest possible idle RPM for a long descent (min fuel consumption), and also for ground operations (min thrust -- not riding the brakes during taxi, plus minimize fuel burn).  In certain cases, though, you want a slightly higher power setting, even when the thrust levers are closed against the idle (aft) stop.

- When using significant amounts of bleed air for anti-icing or de-icing would be one case where a FADEC (or a less-automated predecessor system) would command a slightly higher idle.
- Some aircraft may have an "approach idle" where the min power setting while on approach -- defined however, perhaps in terms of altitude and/or configuration -- is kept higher than otherwise so that power is more immediately available in the event of a go-around.

For a turboprop, you're typically running at constant propeller RPM, and the difference between high power and low power is a matter of the blade angle.  Flight idle would keep the RPM high but the blade angle flat -- taking a minimal "bite" out of the air, doing little work, generating minimal or no thrust, and having the blades moderately "flat" in reference to the oncoming airflow.  But, the prop is still rotating at the nominal speed in terms of RPM.  On the ground, the requirements change, and you can accept (or may find desirable) an even flatter blade angle and a lower RPM than you would in flight.  Thus, the "ground idle" option that accomplishes those things, burning less fuel (since the prop is spinning more slowly and is taking even less bit out of the air, generating no thrust) and generating less noise.

In both the jet and the turboprop case, you can have different idle settings, but they are there to accomplish different purposes, driven by the presence or absence of the propeller and its constant RPM & varying pitch.  In the jet, the switch between idle modes is generally transparent to the pilot; you know which one applies "now" by noting your N1 RPM when at idle.  In the turboprop, ground idle is typically selected by the pilot.

Comment: Why would a pilot need flight idle instead of ground idle while in-flight? Aren't the economic and flight requirements identical, meaning a ground idle with lower RPM and "even flatter" blade angle is advantageous, especially when go-around power is more easily achievable in a turboprop?

Comment: Flat blades become a major source of drag - known as "going into Beta range" right after landing. The lowest blade angle you *need* in flight is Flight Idle; the really flat blades & much slower engine speed (from which spool-up *would* take significant time) is reserved for ground use - thus, Ground Idle.